# Extend an existing class in Angular 2 for Leaflet TileLayer

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to adapt this tutorial in angular 2. https://kuamoto.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/myth-1-cant-make-offline-apps/comment-page-1/#comment-17

I found this related issue :
[Leaflet: Can't extend TileLayer with typescript 2.0 & angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470051/leaflet-cant-extend-tilelayer-with-typescript-2-0-angular-2)
I don't know if I have the correct index.d.ts file (I provided it below)

I get the following error while I try to extend tileLayer :  Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'typeof tileLayer'

```
var lyr = L.tileLayer.extend({
    mbTilesDB: null,

    initialize: function(url, options, db) {
        console.log("sql plugin: " + db);
        this.mbTilesDB = db;
    },
    getTileUrl: function(tilePoint, zoom, tile) {
        [...]
    },
    _loadTile: function(tile, tilePoint, zoom) {
        tile._layer = this;
        tile.onload = this._tileOnLoad;
        tile.onerror = this._tileOnError;
        this.getTileUrl(tilePoint, zoom, tile);
    }
});
```

This is how I import Leaflet :

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

And this is the extract from the index.d.ts file related to TileLayer :

```
export interface TileLayerOptions extends GridLayerOptions {
    minZoom?: number;
    maxZoom?: number;
    maxNativeZoom?: number;
    subdomains?: string | Array<string>;
    errorTileUrl?: string;
    zoomOffset?: number;
    tms?: boolean;
    zoomReverse?: boolean;
    detectRetina?: boolean;
    crossOrigin?: boolean;
    [name: string]: any;
}

export interface TileLayer extends GridLayer {
    setUrl(url: string, noRedraw?: boolean): this;
}

export function tileLayer(urlTemplate: string, options?: TileLayerOptions): TileLayer;

export interface WMSOptions extends TileLayerOptions {
    layers: string;
    styles?: string;
    format?: string;
    transparent?: boolean;
    version?: string;
    crs?: CRS;
    uppercase?: boolean;
}

export interface WMS extends TileLayer {
    setParams(params: Object, noRedraw?: boolean): this;
}

export namespace tileLayer {
    export function wms(baseUrl: string, options: WMSOptions): WMS;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Based on what is written in the following bug report https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11693 it doesn't look like the extend functions are fully implemented in the typescript binding. The recommended approach from the article is to use the following syntax:

```
var lyr = (L.tileLayer as any).extend({});
```

This make the the project compile for me.